# encrypt vs sign, rare output with Crypt_RSA

Tags: php, xml, encryption, sign, phpseclib

I am trying to sign a string with:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//$rsa->setPassword('*****');
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('i.pem')); // private key
$plaintext = 'f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c';
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->sign($plaintext);
$reto = base64_encode($ciphertext);
```

when I verify it locally, with:

```
$pubb_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('instancia_imta_ope.crt'));      
$keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($pubb_key);
$pkeyy = $keyData['key'];
$rsa->loadKey($pkeyy); // PUBLIC key
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $ciphertext) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```

it shows VERIFIED,
when I use a tester page with my broker, THIS SAME CODE, doesnt work. It doesnt recover the original string.
Trying to use something different, I tried the following weird code:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('i.pem')); // PRIVATE key, IT SHOULD BE PUBLIC
$plaintext = 'f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c';
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
$reto = base64_encode($ciphertext);
```

its weird or not logical, because I am using a private key to encrypt, it is suposed to be the public key, son the target uses its private key, to deencrypt the message. Strangely, this weid code makes the tester page send an OK, it recovers the string. I dont know why.
All this is part of a bigger message, which it is finally processed with xml signature, when I process all (adding the xml signature), the other tester page of the broker sends invalid signatures, I can bet that it is because of the weird code. Never mind, question:
WHY THE CORRECT CODE (rsa->sign....) DOESNT WORK? WHAT DO YOU THING OF ALL THIS?
thanks
mario

Comment: Maybe the weird code it is correct, encrypt with private key, and all people with decrypt, but only with my public, key, maybe that's why the first page, sends OK

Comment: So maybe my doubt is, why the two codes, one with rsa->sign and the toher one with rsa->encrypt, dont give the same result, thanks for clarifyin it

Answer (score 2):

So the code works on one machine but not the other? Seems like in that case your .crt files might be different. That said, you don't need to use `openssl_*` to extract the public key - you can do so with phpseclib just fine. eg.

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('...'); // see google.crt

echo $x509->getPublicKey()->getPublicKey();
?>
```

I'm not really sure what you're asking about with the encryption question.. although normally you'd encrypt with the public key you can do so with the private key as well. They both do the same operation - a modular exponentiation. I can't comment on the tester page since the source to it hasn't been posted.

Comment: Hi neubert, not exactly, the code works in a first tester, this first tester only test the sign of the string f2e this sign is part of a document, then I xml signature the whole document then, the resulting signed doc it is tested in a second tester, there it sends "invalid signatures". What I like to happen is to apply code for sign the string then apply the xml signature to whole document and put the resulting signed doc in the tester.I cannot reach this point, because, when I sigh the string with private key, the first tester, sends an error, doesnt recover original string, it puts, garbage

Comment: Can you post the non-working code then? It sounds like you posted the working code and then some unrelated code related to encryption but I see nothing relating to the XML signatures in your OP. How are you generating them with Crypt_RSA and how are you verifying them? idk too much about XML signatures but I do know that the XML has to be canonicalized before generating the sigs so you'll always get the same sig. Without canoicalization `<tag1><tag2>val</tag2></tag1>` and `<tag1> <tag2>val</tag2> </tag1>` could very well be seen as the same thing, for instance.

Comment: $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    //$rsa->setPassword('*****');
    $rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('i.pem')); // private key
    $plaintext = 'f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c';
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
    $ciphertext = $rsa->sign($plaintext);
    $reto = base64_encode($ciphertext);

Comment: this previous code is not working in the tester. I dont know why, it is using private key and the private function, it should work, what is wrong with it?

Comment: link of first tester: https://ope.gob.mx/BrokerInteropQA/Diagnostico/seguridad.aspx

Comment: link of second tester: https://ope.gob.mx/BrokerInteropQA/Diagnostico/default.aspx

Comment: I tried even with the following, and the tester doesnt recovers original string:$pkeyid = file_get_contents('i.pem'); //private key
$data = 'f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c';
// compute signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid,OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
$reto = base64_encode($signature);

Comment: put some inf above @neubert

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with encryption and certification. You SIGN using a private key, which guarantees that it came from you (or AN Other holder of the key which should be kept safely in a secure keystore).

You ENCRYPT with a public key, so that only the intended recipient can decrypt (again or AN Other holder of the private key of the asymmetric pair).

This is how SSL works roughly under the hood (skipping the encrypted AES symmetric key part).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, thats why I put weird, any idea why the sign code (first parragraph of code) doesnt work?

Comment: ", when I use a tester page with my broker, THIS SAME CODE, doesnt work" - I'd have to see the test page really. There will be a difference you're missing, possibly you're forgetting to Base64 decode?

Comment: Jeff, you mean the code inside the tester page? agree, I will request it to the broker, to see how are validating...

Comment: But first, I would have to fix this first part, sign correctly that part of the message (the string f2e140eb-....."). Maybe with that solved, the tester runs Ok

Comment: clarifying, the first test page, validates, the sign of the string, the second test page, validates the whole message, with the xml signature already included. The first page is what I am trying to solve, but not with the ilogical code, but with the sign code

Answer (score 0):

Example of whole doc (fields truncated for security), SEE UPPERSOCRE COMMENTS PLEASE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<SolicitudRegistro xmlns="http://www.cidge.gob.mx/SCG/Interoperabilidad"     
IdMensaje="f2e140eb-2b09-44ab-8504-87b25d81914c">
<FechaEnvio>2013-04-19T02:09:08</FechaEnvio>
<Registrante EndPoint="https://200.34.175.46:443/InteropOPE    
/MensajeInteroperabilidadService" Nombre="Institnologia del Agua"  
NombreCorto="IMTA" URI="op.mx">
<DatosDeContacto AreaOficina="Inmatica" 
CorreoElectronico="jbloc.imta.mx"     
Nombre="JoChacon" Puesto="Subdireclecomunicaciones">
<Telefonos>
<Telefono Extension=" " NumeroTelefonico="7773293644"/>
</Telefonos>
</DatosDeContacto>
<CertificadoInstancia>MIIFETCCA/mgAwIBAgIUMDAwMDAwM
</Registrante>
<Reto>         //THIS IS THE STRING SIGNED WITH PRIVATE KEY, is part of info
<CadenaCifrada>Ln0BAsnwrNg6IzjW7hk2c/Nxx/x  //I COPY THIS IN FIRST TESTER AND FAILS
</Reto>                              //UNLESS I USE ENCRYPT CODE WITH PRIV KEY (RARE)
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-
c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI=""><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09 
/xmldsig#enveloped-signatu
<ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data>   
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIFETCCA/mgAwIBAgIUMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDI1MzMwDQY
```

Comment: Is this the solution now or just an additional comment or just something else? How is this related to your question? Can you make more clear what the comments are about?

Comment: Sure hakre, this code represents the final document, with xml signature. There is a field (reto) that was signed with the Crypt_RSA functions. The broker has a page to test this first signature, which doesnt work (so I cannont reach 2nd page). If I use encrypt function to sign instead, this first page sends ok, but then the second tester page for the whole doc, fails, it indicates invalid signatures, thats why I was asking WHAT IS WRONG WITH THE FIRST CODE, hope somebody sees the problem.

Comment: the code of the post, is for the sign of the reto field, the code for generating the whole doc, is not presented